# Relative path not working with express subdomain and ui router

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, subdomain

I am getting serious problem while using  "express-subdomain-handler" with angular ui router. I have created different apps for different subdomain.
Normally site runs well for primary domain: http://localhost:3002/#/
But when sub domain rel called : http://test.localhost:3002/#/, I have different app templeate say "index.html". The JS and CSS included  has  relative path and now it shows 404 error by calling  http://test.localhost:3002/#/PATHTOJSORCSS directory.

I want this to be called the path http://localhost:3002/#/PATHTOJSORCSS
Please help.